# How to prevent user to direct access to servlets when using MVC

Tags: jsp

I am using netbeans with glass fish v2. I made a project with two jsp files and a servlet. Here is my file structure

[image: Project Structure]

Here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShoppingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pk.mazars.basitMahmood.eBookShopping.ShoppingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShoppingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShoppingServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Now if i write in the browser `http://localhost:11747/eBookShop/`, then it open the first page and if i write `http://localhost:11747/eBookShop/ShoppingServlet`, then it still opens the first page.  How can i prevent user to direct access my servlet. I tried to make a package in the WEB-INF by right clicking on it and then select new package, but it still create new package in the Source Packages. How can i prevent direct access to servlets?

Thanks

EDIT

---

[image]

Comment: Why would you *want* to?

Comment: Because i read that when you use MVC then it is better to put your servlet in WEB-INF because client can't directly access the files that are in WEB-INF. I am new to JSP. Is it ok to use the same structure that i am using ?

Comment: It's JSPs that should be in WEB-INF to prevent direct access.

Comment: oh you mean i put my jsp files in WEB-INF, no need to put java classes(servlet)? Although i am using glass fish but i am reading a book in which author used Tom Cat. In the book he show a directory structure in which java classes are in the WEB-INF. I am modifying my question to put a screen shot, shot please check it out.

Comment: `WEB-INF/classes` is just where classes go--that's part of the default web app directory layout, just like jar files go in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: But source files(.java) are also under WEB-INF. You can see that in the picture.  This is confusing me. Not jsp files

Comment: It makes no *sense* to put the Java files under WEB-INF, but it doesn't really matter (especially while just testing). *I* wouldn't put them there, I'd have a separate source directory. You're the one that created the JSP files not under WEB-INF; you can always move them.

Comment: hhhmmm actually i am following the book that's why i tried to do the same as author :). Ok i move my jsp files in the WEB-INF. But i want to ask after moving my jsp files under WEB-INF, if i type `http://localhost:11747/eBookShop/` , then my servlet wil get invoke or my index.jsp?

Comment: JSP files you *need* to access directly obviously shouldn't be under WEB-INF.